# ASP.NET Core RC2 TagHelperOutput.Content.Append changes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

With RC1 you could construct a new TagBuilder, and just append that to the output of a custom TagHelper as such:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
   var indicator = new TagBuilder("span");
   indicator.AddCssClass("indicator");
   output.Content.Append(indicator);
}
```

That now fails with RC2, as `TagHelperOutput.Content.Append()` only accepts a `string`.

I can mess about with `TagBuilder.WriteTo()`, but that seems overly complex compared to how it was.

Is there a new way to construct new tags and append to the output that I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RC2 you can use

```
output.Content.AppendHtml(tag);
```

Sample of menu tag helper:

view:

```
<ul>
  <menu action="Index" controller="Home">Home page</menu>
  <menu action="List" controller="Home">List</menu>
</ul>
```

MenuTagHelper.cs:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "controller, action")]
public class MenuTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;

    public MenuTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory)
    {
        this.urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action(Action, Controller);
        var text = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();

        output.TagName = "li";

        var a = new TagBuilder("a");
        a.MergeAttribute("href", $"{url}");
        a.MergeAttribute("title", text);
        a.InnerHtml.Append(text);

        var routeData = ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
        var currentController = routeData["controller"];
        var currentAction = routeData["action"];

        if (string.Equals(Action, currentAction as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(Controller, currentController as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            output.Attributes.Add("class", "active");

        output.Content.AppendHtml(a);
    }
}
```